# My MVC 3.0 application won't work on Visual Studio 2012. Why?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I have a standard MVC 3.0 application done with VS 2010. When I tried to open it with VS 2012 it didn't load and shown an `incompatible` label next to the project name.

The error details are as follows:

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them. You can still open these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
     - Cerebello, "D:\Projetos\Azure\X\X\X.ccproj"


Non-functional changes required
Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in this version and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.
     - Cerebello, "D:\Projetos\Azure\X\X.sln"
```

I'm googling with no results.

What may be happening?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the Windows Azure SDK for .NET - June 2012 SP1.  `*.ccproj` files are Azure projects.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30651